# How to find frequency of a square wave using FFT

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

In the FFT (second) plot, I am expecting a bigger peak at frequency = 1.0, compared to other frequencies, since it is a 1 Hz Square Wave signal sampled at 5Hz.

*I am a beginner at this, possibly missing something silly here*
Here's what I have done:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
t500 = np.linspace(0,5,500,endpoint=False)
s1t500 = signal.square(2*np.pi*1.0*t500)
```

First plot shows 1 Hz Square Wave sampled at 5Hz for 5 seconds:

```
t5 = np.linspace(0,5,25,endpoint=False)
t5 = t5 + 1e-14
s1t5 = signal.square(2.0*np.pi*1.0*t5)
plt.ylim(-2,2); plt.plot(t500,s1t500,'k',t5,s1t5,'b',t5,s1t5,'bo'); plt.show()
```

[image: 1 Hz Square Wave sampled at 5Hz]

Here in the Second plot, I am expecting the magnitude at f=1 Hz to be more than at f=2. Am I missing something ?

```
y1t5 = np.fft.fft(s1t5)
ff1t5 = np.fft.fftfreq(25,d=0.2)
plt.plot(ff1t5,y1t5); plt.show()
```

[image: FFT for 1 Hz Square Wave sampled at 5Hz]

Comment: This seems to be a property of DFT, I found a similar example in the matlab documentation: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/discrete-fourier-transform-dft.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you missed the fact that Fourier transform produces functions (or sequences of numbers in case of DFT/FFT) in complex space:

```
>>> np.fft.fft(s1t5)
[ 5. +0.j          0. +0.j          0. +0.j          0. +0.j          0. +0.j
  5.-15.38841769j  0. +0.j          0. +0.j          0. +0.j          0. +0.j
  5. +3.63271264j  0. +0.j          0. +0.j          0. +0.j          0. +0.j
# and so on
```

In order to see the amplitude spectrum on your plot, apply `np.absolute` or `abs`:

```
>>> np.absolute(np.fft.fft(s1t5))
[  5.           0.           0.           0.           0.          16.18033989
   0.           0.           0.           0.           6.18033989   0.           0.
   0.           0.           6.18033989   0.           0.           0.           0.
   16.18033989  0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
```

Otherwise only real part will be shown.

Comment: What if I use `np.fft.rfft`, should this not return the expected 1/n dependency?

Comment: If you have a symmetric square-wave, then the FFT will be all-real (to machine precision): here’s an example of that in Matlab: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/07/16/complex-surprises-from-fft/

Comment: @AhmedFasih OP transforms not the actual 1 Hz square wave, but a set of samples made at 5 Hz sampling rate. This introduces the imaginary part.

Comment: @jojonas not sure what's the difference between `fft` and `rfft` (the latter is a local numpy term), but they both return the same result for your case.

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 Thanks, my bad! @jojonas note that doing `fft` or `rfft`on the above examples returned the same result except that `fft` provided same output symmetrically on the right (-ve) side of the origin (including the nyquist component).